# Java volatile and cache coherence

Tags: java, volatile

If cache coherency is implemented at hardware level why do we need volatile? Any core/processor should get the latest value anyway?

Or is it dealing with a different issue completely?

Comment: You may want to read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441279/volatile-guarantees-and-out-of-order-execution), or the Java Language Specification, where this is explained.

Comment: @vanza the question you provided does not refer to the **cache coherency** keyword

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Cache coherence may be implemented at the processor level but, unless the [processor memory model](http://preshing.com/20120930/weak-vs-strong-memory-models/) guarantees sequential consistency (which is not the case on most modern architectures), you will only get cache coherence if you ask for it.

That is what volatile is for: it asks the JVM to produce the relevant machine instruction(s) that will ask the processor(s) to synchronize its cache with main memory.

Comment: What instruction does that?

Comment: I believe that @assylias is referring to instruction reordering (please correct me if I am wrong). Although threads will always see the latest value (be it read from the RAM or cache), there is no guarantee that the instructions will not be reordered.